# Disk error: physical (hardware) error or just filesystem?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, smart

I've been getting errors now and then with my [ADATA HD330 2TB disk (ST2000LM007-1R8174)](https://www.adata.com/en/feature/555), e.g. in some directories:

[image]

Also, the LED sometimes blinks red while also blinking blue, which is a bit strange:

[image]

, since this is not described in the [datasheet](http://www.adata.com/upload/downloadfile/Datasheet-HD330_20191008.pdf), see below; pure red should mean "shock" (well, the disk is stationary on the table), but this blinked red AND blue.

[image]

### So, how do I find if the error(s) is physical (hardware) or not?

I need to know if it's case to apply the warranty claim. It could be just a filesystem error (I noticed that the USB cable had bad contact, so I changed it, so the errors might originate due to that), or it could be physical disk error. I don't want to just repair the filesystem without knowing if it's physical error i.e. the case for applying warranty.

I tried to use Crystal Disk Info (see below), but I am not any wiser after seeing this:

[image]

**EDIT:** chkdsk output. How do I know if these errors are hardware errors, or just filesystem errors?

```
C:\Users\Tomas>chkdsk d:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
The volume is in use by another process. Chkdsk
might report errors when no corruption is present.
Volume label is Nový svazek.

WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Attribute record (A0, $I30) from file record segment 30FC6
is corrupt.
Attribute record (A0, $I30) from file record segment 30FF0
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 30FF1
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 30FF2
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 30FF3
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 30FF4
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 30FF5
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 30FF6
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 30FF7
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 30FF8
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 30FF9
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 30FFA
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 30FFC
is corrupt.
  394752 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  302 large file records processed.

Errors found.  CHKDSK cannot continue in read-only mode.
```

Answer (score 2):

The S.M.A.R.T. data does not show any of the classical indicators of physical drive failure. (Reallocated/pending sectors, uncorrectable errors, all look good. Read error rate looks maybe not so good but some number is expected and if they're low enough to be correctable they seem to be within expected ranges - they are above threshold.)

Your next step should be to run a S.M.A.R.T. self-test. On Windows, this can be done with gsmartctl. The short test can be run directly. If you wish to run the long test, you might need to set up a scripted looping file access to prevent the disk from going to sleep.

It's also possible that this is a USB <=> SATA controller board failure. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to diagnose such an error, but you might try and see if you can cause it to happen with a long-running drive benchmark, e.g. using HD Tune. Those are largely filesystem-agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

Run CHKDSK without any Fix parameter (/F) on the affected drive. If if reports numerous errors, make a screen print and return the drive under warranty

Comment: Thanks John, but this is just a filesystem check, isn't it? How do I recognize from the CHKDSK output what is physical disk error and what is a filesystem error?

Comment: CHKDSK also checks the drive for physical errors. Get a screen shot, edit your question and post a screen shot of the errors

Comment: Thanks John. It's a bit tricky since the chkdsk output was unfortunatelly localized into my national language, do you know - is there a way to switch it's output to English?

Comment: I cannot help with translation. Maybe some one else can or Google to translate it for you.

Comment: Done. Please check the updated answer :-)

Comment: If this is Windows 10: `chkdsk /offlinescanandfix /x f:`, but if its <=Windows 8: `chkdsk /r /x f:`

Comment: The errors say damaged file "
Removing a corrupted attribute record (160. $ 130)
from segment 200646 of the file record.
Deleting a damaged attribute record (160. $ 130)
from segment 200688 file record.
! Removing the corrupted attribute record (128. .. ..)
, from the 200689 file record segment.
Deleting a damaged attribute record (128, "")
from segment 200690 file record.
Deleting a damaged attribute record (128. "")"  If you can delete the damaged files, and then check, the disk may be fine

Comment: Thank you both guys, however the question was how to figure out if the error is PHYSICAL/HARDWARE, not to fix filesystem error. I am asking again: **How do I recognize from the CHKDSK output what is physical disk error and what is a filesystem error?**

Comment: The post I made above (translation of the errors) shows file errors and not disk errors

Comment: ok thanks. So, can `chkdsk` be even any useful to my question?

Comment: If it does not show errors (other that File Corruption errors) then it is a useful answer

Answer (score 0):

As I had a similar case recently, my recommendation is this:
Try to backup as much as possible to a new disk and recycle your disk.
While copying away files, you'll see how fast or slow it is:
If there are just logical errors (filesystem), the copy will be fast.
However if there are physical problems, copying will be slow (up to a value that it won't succeed after a year).
If you want to send in the disk for warranty ever, you'll have to backup your data anyway (before deleting it on the bad disk).

Reasoning: I think your disk got a "shock" while writing.
You have a high "seek error rate" and "read error rate" (if the raw values are correct). Maybe try smartmontools instead.

Also the bad cable could have caused logical consistency errors on the filesystem (that chkdsk should be able to fix unless the disk has a write cache)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know if it's case to apply the warranty claim.

To determine this you have to read all sectors to uncover unreadable ones.

Runnning checkdisk with the /F and /R parameters could help.

Running ddrescue by copying to the null device would list you all the locations of unreadables sectors in the logfile. Furthermore each unreadable sector would increase the pending sector count in the SMART parameters.

Keep in mind that abusive handling of the drive will cause errors as well and you have no means of proof if your dealer pretends that possible errors have been caused by your handling.

Other errors are possible as well but you would need to backup your drive before putting a heavy load with a tool like Iometer on it.